# Kubernetes: how to set VolumeMount user group and file permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using kops. I've mounted an EBS volume onto a container and it is visible from my application but it's read only because my application does not run as root. How can I mount a `PersistentVolumeClaim` as a user other than root? The `VolumeMount` does not seem to have any options to control the user, group or file permissions of the mounted path.

Here is my Deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: notebook-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: notebook-1
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: notebook-1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: notebook-1
      containers:
      - name: notebook-1
        image: jupyter/base-notebook
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/home/jovyan/work"
          name: notebook-1
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The Pod Security Context supports setting an `fsGroup`, which allows you to set the group ID that owns the volume, and thus who can write to it. The example in the docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  # specification of the pod's containers
  # ...
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1234
```

More info on this is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/security-context/)

Comment: also note the `volumes.*.defaultMode` field to set security bits - https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod

Comment: Hi, doesn't solve the use cas where you need to set readOnly permission on some file when you software requires it. I'm struggling with that issue, trying to avoid creating a permissive PSP, willing to keep RunAsUser: MustRunAsNonRoot, since this will apply to all the containers in the pod. I'm thinking about creating a custom image with sudoers specific rule to perform chmod/chown with sudo for a non-root user, that I'll call as initContainer image . Any bettter/working idea welcome.

Comment: `securityContext` is a valid way to do this, but you have it in `spec.container` when it needs to be `spec`. Note: there is a `securityContext` in `spec.container`, but that's different than the one at the spec level. `fsGroup` is not available at the container level `securityContext`.

Comment: I just want to add, that this is what you probably need if you are running unprivileged Pods. Volumes are usually mounted using root:root, which might lead to "Permission denied" errors. But setting `fsGroup` and possibly `defaultMode` helps mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 95):

I ended up with an `initContainer` with the same `volumeMount` as the main container to set proper permissions, in my case, for a custom Grafana image.

This is necessary when a container in a pod is running as a user other than `root` and needs write permissions on a mounted volume.

```
initContainers:
- name: take-data-dir-ownership
  image: alpine:3
  # Give `grafana` user (id 472) permissions a mounted volume
  # https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile
  command:
  - chown
  - -R
  - 472:472
  - /var/lib/grafana
  volumeMounts:
  - name: data
    mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
```

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

**Update:** Note that it might suffice to run `chown` without the `-R` (recursive) flag, since the permissions will generally be persisted within the volume itself, regardless of pod restarts. This will be desirable if there are large amounts of files in the volume, as it will take time to process all of them (depending on the `resources` limits that are set for the `initContainer`).

**Update 2:** In Kubernetes v1.23 [`securityContext.fsGroup` and `securityContext.fsGroupChangePolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) features went into GA/stable. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545277/90674) for more information. The [related changelog item](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#skip-volume-ownership-change-graduates-to-ga) describes this as

> The feature to configure volume permission and ownership change policy for Pods moved to GA in 1.23. This allows users to skip recursive permission changes on mount and speeds up the pod start up time.

Comment: Didn't you have to run the initContainer as root user? Otherwise how would it have permission to chown to a non-root user?

Comment: @Oliver: In this example, the initContainer is run as root implicitly. The main container will be run with a user specified in the image itself, unless `container.securityContext.runAsUser` or `container.securityContext.runAsNonRoot` (or others) have been explicitly set to something else. [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#securitycontext-v1-core)

Comment: When I am deploying grafana (as you did) `securityContext` and `fsGroup: 472` is enough.

Comment: I used a similar approach for my application, and ended up encapsulating it in the following repo: https://github.com/mcg1969/pvc-subpath-init

Answer (score 38):

This came as one of the challenges for the Kubernetes Deployments/StatefulSets, when you have to run process inside a container as non-root user. But, when you mount a volume to a  pod, it always gets mounted with the permission of `root:root`.

So, the non-root user must have access to the folder where it wants to read and write data.

Please follow the below steps for the same.

1. Create user group and assign group ID in Dockerfile.
2. Create user with user ID and add to the group in Dockerfile.
3. change ownership recursively for the folders the user process wants to read/write.
4. Add the below lines in Deployment/StatefulSet in pod `spec` context.

   ```
   spec:
     securityContext:
       runAsUser: 1099
       runAsGroup: 1099
       fsGroup: 1099
   ```

**runAsUser**

Specifies that for any Containers in the Pod, all processes run with user ID 1099.

**runAsGroup**

Specifies the primary group ID of 1099 for all processes within any containers of the Pod.

If this field is omitted, the primary group ID of the containers will be `root(0)`.

Any files created will also be owned by user 1099 and group 1099 when `runAsGroup` is specified.

**fsGroup**

Specifies the owner of any volume attached will be owner by group ID 1099.

Any files created under it will be having permission of `nonrootgroup:nonrootgroup`.

Comment: Doing God's work! Thanks you! fsGroup is EXACLY what I needed! Thank you kind sir!

Comment: What about when your image is `FROM scratch`, can't really add a user or a group.

Answer (score 9):

For k8s version 1.10+, `runAsGroup` has been added, it's similar to `fsGroup` but works differently.

Implementation can be tracked here: https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/213

Comment: When you specify `runAsGroup` the container is started as that group but the ownership for volume does not change. So they are different, I used both to make my volumes writable.

Comment: Add fsgroup as well. Once you add fsgroup context then only it will also see runasgroup context to set the ownership of the folder. You can add the same user to fsgroup as runasgroup or add supplementary user group  to fsgroup.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630

If it is an `emptydir`, the `securityContext` in the `spec` can be used:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    fsGroup: 1000
containers: ...
```

If the volume is a `hostpath`, an `initContainer` can be used to `chown` paths in the volume:

```
initContainers:
    - name: example-c
      image: busybox:latest
      command: ["sh","-c","mkdir -p /vol-path && chown -R 1000:1000 /vol-path"]
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 1Gi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: vol-example
          mountPath: /vol-path
```

Answer (score 4):

- In minikube, it worked after running `initContainers` as a **root** user , by setting `runAsUser: 0`

```
    initContainers:
      - name: change-ownership-container
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chown","-R","1000:1000", "/home/jovyan/work"]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: notebook-data
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/work
```

So the whole Yaml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jupyter
  labels:
    release: jupyter
spec:
  replicas:
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  serviceName: jupyter-headless
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: jupyter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        release: jupyter
      annotations:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: jupyter
        image: "jupyter/base-notebook:ubuntu-20.04"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8888
          protocol: TCP
        - name: blockmanager
          containerPort: 7777
          protocol: TCP
        - name: driver
          containerPort: 2222
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: notebook-data
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/work
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 300Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
      initContainers:
      - name: change-ownership-container
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chown","-R","1000:1000", "/home/jovyan/work"]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: notebook-data
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/work
      volumes:
      - name: notebook-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jupyter-pvc
```

Comment: does it have to be privileged? I think RunAsUser:0 would suffice

Answer (score 2):

> For people using configmap as file inside pod

I am loading data from a configmap as file inside the pod's container here are my manifests:

```yaml
#./script-cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: script-cm
  labels:
    app: script
data:
  data-script: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
    echo "some script commands"
```

```yaml
#./deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  script
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app:  script
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: script
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:  script
    spec:              
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name:  script-container
        image:  ubuntu:20.04
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: influxdb-provisioning
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sh           
          subPath: data.sh     

      volumes:
        - name: script-bind
          configMap:
            name: script-cm
            items:
              - key: data-script
                path: data.sh         
                mode: 0777
```

As you can see I am following [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume) to bind a config map into the pod, `mode: 0777` allowed me to give `execution permissions`  on that specific file, you can also run the following command to get a better idea using `kubectl explain`:

```bash
kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes.configMap.items.mode
```

> Make sure to put the right permissions instead of 0777 since it's not recommended especially on sensitive data!

Answer (score 2):

There is now also the fsGroupChangePolicy that you can specify in the security context. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/14/kubernetes-release-1.20-fsgroupchangepolicy-fsgrouppolicy/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution of this problem:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: volume-permissions
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "chmod -R 755 /data && chown 1000:1000 /data"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-volume
      mountPath: /data
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-volume
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used `scratch` as the base image and set the user to 65543. And I needed the write permission to a dir. I did this by using `emptyDir` volume,

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    ...
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp
        name: tmp
        # readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: tmp
    emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the file system permission run the `initcontainer` before actual container start

here example for elastic search pod

```
initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
        - chgrp 1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: set-dir-owner
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:                         #Volume mount path
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
```

To change user group in container

```
spec:
      containers:
      securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, you use twice the 'privileged' directive, which is here useless, and absolutely bad [security] practice.

Comment: @tisc0 sorry for that however updated answer no need to use in init container.

Comment: @tisc0 thankyou so much for pointing it out and correcting me hope it will helpful to others also.

Comment: You're welcome. Though, I thing in your second part of code, 'To change user group in container', you're still using privileged, and I'm not seeing anything like runAsGroup or fsGroup. (Don't want to bother, just thorought).

Answer (score 0):

Over a few iterations later, I ended up using

```
{{- $root := . }}
...
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-mount-hack
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "find /data -user root -exec chown 33:33 {} \\;"]
        volumeMounts:
{{- range $key,$val := .Values.persistence.mounts }}
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data/{{ $key }}
          subPath: {{ $root.Values.projectKey }}/{{ $key }}
{{- end }}
```

It's much cleaner and configurable as opposed to other solutions. Moreover, it is way **faster** - the find command only changes permissions on files/directories that actually belong to the root user.

When you are mounting volumes with a large number of files, this can have a significant impact on your container boot/load times (seconds or even minutes!).

Try comparing the execution time of

`chown www-data:www-data ./ -R`

and

`find /data -user root -exec chown 33:33 {} \\;`

you may be surprised!