# Kubernetes - setting custom permissions/file ownership per volume (and not per pod)

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to set per-volume permissions/ownership in Kubernetes declaratively?

Usecase:

- a pod is composed of two containers, running as two distinct users/groups, both of them non-root, and are unable to `sudo`
- the containers mount a volume each, and need to create files in these volumes (e.g. both of them want to write logs)

We know that we can use `fsGroup`, however that is a pod-level declaration. So even if we pick fsGroup equal to user in first container, then we are going to have permission issues in the other one. (ref: [Kubernetes: how to set VolumeMount user group and file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370/kubernetes-how-to-set-volumemount-user-group-and-file-permissions))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to **use init-container to change permissions of mounted directories**.

The init-container would need to mount both volumes (from both containers), and do the needed `chown`/`chmod` operations.

Drawbacks:

- extra container that needs to be aware of other containers' specific (ie. uid/gid)
- init container needs to run as root to perform `chown`

Comment: Hi @Adam - were you able to find an alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with adding one init container with root access.

```
    initContainers:
    - name: changeowner
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 200:200 /<volume>"]   
      volumeMounts:
      - name: <your volume>
        mountPath: /<volume>
```