# Volumemounts created as root:artifact though security context provided

Tags: kubernetes

**Issue:** 
Deploying Artifactory as a deployment in Kubernetes. The VolumeMounts are being mounted as root:artifact and permissions of drwxr-sr-x

```
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
drwxr-sr-x    2 root     artifact      4096 Jan 24 17:52 etc
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     artifact      1048 Jan 24 17:48 artifactory.config.import.yml
-rw-r--r--    1 root     artifact     12703 Jan 24 17:48 artifactory.system.properties
```

**Expected:**
The VolumeMount should be mounted as artifact:artifact with read and write permissions

kubernetes manifest file its incomplete due to restriction

```
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1030
        runAsGroup: 1030
        fsGroup: 1030

        volumeMounts:
        - name: artifactory-volume
          mountPath: "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory"
        - name: bootstrap
          mountPath: "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.config.import.yml"
          subPath: bootstrap
        - name: artifactory-system-properties
          mountPath: "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.system.properties"
          subPath: artifactory.system.properties
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "3"
            memory: 6Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 4Gi


      volumes:
      - name: bootstrap
        secret:
          secretName: artifactory6170-artifactory
      - name: artifactory-system-properties
        configMap:
          name: artifactory6170-artifactory-system-properties
      - name: artifactory-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: artifactory6170-artifactory
```

**Kubernetes Version :**

```
Server Version: version.Info{
  Major: "1",
  Minor: "14",
  GitVersion: "v1.14.1",
  GitCommit: "b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290",
  GitTreeState: "clean",
  BuildDate: "2019-04-08T17:02:58Z",
  GoVersion: "go1.12.1",
  Compiler: "gc",
  Platform: "linux/amd64"
}
```

I believe the  security context covers the required

```
        runAsUser: 1030
```

runs the process as 1030

```
        runAsGroup: 1030
```

Any files created will also be owned by user 1030 and group 1030 when runAsGroup is specified.
runs

```
        fsGroup: 1030
```

the owner of any volume attached will be owner by group ID 1099.

**[Docker file path](https://github.com/binnythomas-1989/artifactory/blob/master/Dockerfile)**

Not sure why the container comes up with wrong user ownership, any help would be really appreciated.

Error:

```
kubectl logs artifactory6170-artifactory-756cffb9-68zjj
2020-01-26 12:28:13  [719 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
2020-01-26 12:28:13  [720 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Running as uid=1030(artifactory) gid=1030(artifactory) groups=1030(artifactory)
2020-01-26 12:28:13   [57 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
2020-01-26 12:28:13   [58 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-pro/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
2020-01-26 12:28:13   [63 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking open files and processes limits
2020-01-26 12:28:13   [66 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open files is 1048576
2020-01-26 12:28:13   [78 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open processes is unlimited
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [211 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Testing directory /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory has read/write permissions for user 'artifactory' (id 1030)
/entrypoint-artifactory.sh: line 180: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/test-permissions: Permission denied
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [229 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] ###########################################################
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [230 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory DOES NOT have proper permissions for user 'artifactory' (id 1030)
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [231 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Directory: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory, permissions: 2775, owner: artifactory, group: artifactory
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [232 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Mounted directory must have read/write permissions for user 'artifactory' (id 1030)
2020-01-26 12:31:13  [233 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] ###########################################################
2020-01-26 12:31:13   [47 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] ERROR: Directory /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory has bad permissions for user 'artifactory' (id 1030)
```

Comment: Is the user id `1030` exist on both host and docker image?

Comment: I think, the docker artifactory image should have write permission for the user 1030 on var directory.

Comment: its not using host volume but a cindervolume

Comment: i have added the docker file for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All i had to do was add an initContainer and mount the Configmaps to /tmp and have it moved to the necessary path /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/, instead of mounting the configmap in the volumemount /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory.

Reason: ConfigMaps are ReadOnly hence /etc was and would always be Readonly.

```
  initContainers:
  - name: "grant-permissions"
    image: "busybox:1.26.2"
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    command:
    - 'sh'
    - '-c'
    - 'mkdir /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc ; cp -vf /tmp/artifactory* /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc ; chown -R 1030:1030 /var/opt/jfrog/ ; rm -rfv /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/lost+found'

    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory"
      name: artifactory-volume
    - name: bootstrap
      mountPath: "/tmp/artifactory.config.import.yml"
      subPath: bootstrap
      readOnly: false
    - name: artifactory-system-properties
      mountPath: "/tmp/artifactory.system.properties"
      subPath: artifactory.system.properties
      readOnly: false
```

then mount the volume to the main container that runs artifactory

```
  containers:
  - name: artifactory
    image: "registry.eu02.dsg.arm.com/sqa/artifactory-pro:6.17.0"

  volumeMounts:
  - name: artifactory-volume
    mountPath: "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory"
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/906083/how-to-mount-volume-with-specific-uid-in-kubernetes-pod), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974105/kubernetes-setting-custom-permissions-file-ownership-per-volume-and-not-per-p?rq=1), [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630) you cannot change the permission of mounted directory.

As a work around you can use `initContainer` which runs before the actual container to change the permission to the directory:

```
initContainers:
- name: volume-mount
  image: busybox
  command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1030:1030 <your_directory>"]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: <your volume>
    mountPath: <your mountPath>
```

Comment: Its too generic to say give permissions, that dont fix a problem. Please find my answer above.