# Kubernetes: how to correctly set php-fpm and nginx shared volume permission

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes,

Currently i'm triyng to deploy laravel app on kuberetes. I have setup 1 deployment yaml containing 2 containers (nginx and php-fpm) and a shared volume.

Here's the full yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: operation-service
  labels:
    app: operation-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: operation
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: fastcgi

---
# Create a pod containing the PHP-FPM application (my-php-app)
# and nginx, each mounting the `shared-files` volume to their
# respective /var/www/ directories.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: operation
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: operation
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: operation
    spec:
      volumes:
        # Create the shared files volume to be used in both pods
        - name: shared-files
          emptyDir: {}

        # Secret containing
        - name: secret-volume
          secret:
            secretName: nginxsecret

        # Add the ConfigMap we declared for the conf.d in nginx
        - name: configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: nginxconfigmap

      containers:
        # Our PHP-FPM application
        - image: asia.gcr.io/operations
          name: app
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /app/. /var/www"]

        - image: nginx:latest
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
              name: secret-volume
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
              name: configmap-volume

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testing.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: operation-service
          servicePort: 443
```

Here's my working `nginxconf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # For https
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;

    server_name testing.com;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }


    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}
```

After deploying, my app won't load on the web. Turns out nginx log is returning:

```
[error] 19#19: *64 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/app/storage/framework/views/ba2564046cc89e436fb993df6f661f314e4d2efb.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:185
```

I know how to setup the volume correctly in local docker, how do i set the shared volume permission in kubernetes correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for answer, I manage to setup kubernetes for our production server with php-fpm and nginx.

It requires 2 image, 1 contains `php-fpm` and our code, the other one is `nginx` image with our conf in it.

Also we have to setup a shared volume between those 2 image to access. What I was missing was the `postStart` command to do `chmod` and `php artisan optimize` to make sure I cleared the cache

For future reference, please do `kubectl logs <pods-name>` and `kubectl describe pods <pods-name>` to easily debug and see what happens in every pods

here's the final working config, hope it helps someone in the future

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: operation-service
  labels:
    app: operation-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: operation
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
---
# Create a pod containing the PHP-FPM application (my-php-app)
# and nginx, each mounting the `shared-files` volume to their
# respective /var/www/ directories.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: operation
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: operation
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 50%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: operation
    spec:
      volumes:
        # Create the shared files volume to be used in both pods
        - name: shared-files
          emptyDir: {}
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 82
      containers:
        # Our PHP-FPM application
        - image: asia.gcr.io/3/operations:{{ .Values.version }}
          name: app
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: prod
          - secretRef:
              name: prod
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www
          # Important! After this container has started, the PHP files
          # in our Docker image aren't in the shared volume. We need to
          # get them into the shared volume. If we tried to write directly
          # to this volume from our Docker image the files wouldn't appear
          # in the nginx container.
          #
          # So, after the container has started, copy the PHP files from this
          # container's local filesystem (/app -- added via the Docker image)
          # to the shared volume, which is mounted at /var/www.
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              name: fastcgi
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - "/bin/sh"
                  - "-c"
                  - >
                    cp -r /app/. /var/www &&
                    cd /var/www &&
                    php artisan optimize &&
                    php artisan migrate --force &&
                    chgrp -R www-data /var/www/* &&
                    chmod -R 775 /var/www/*

        # Our nginx container, which uses the configuration declared above,
        # along with the files shared with the PHP-FPM app.
        - image: asia.gcr.io/3/nginx:1.0
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www


# We don't need this anymore as we're not using fastcgi straightaway
# ---

# apiVersion: v1
# kind: ConfigMap
# metadata:
#   name: ingress-cm
# data:
#   SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/var/www/public/index.php$is_args$args"

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: operation-ingress
  labels:
    app: operation-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myservice.com.au
      secretName: kubernetes-tls
  rules:
  - host: myservice.com.au
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: operation-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `init container` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974106/14801225) to change permissions of mounted directories or you can set an `fsGroup` to change the groupID that owns volume as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545277/14801225).

In your case I think it will be easier to set permissions by modifying your "copy" command:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /app/. /var/www"]
```

adding a `chmod` command with appropriate parameters e.g:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /app/. /var/www && chmod -R a+r /var/www"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read the log and clearly mention permission denied which mean Nginx doesn't have permission to access the file you might have to change the permission of directory or files so that Nginx can access it.

either you can change permission during the docker build or else run a prehook or set the command which will run with image at a time of deployment get updated.

something like :

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/vendor
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

i was trying to set up the WordPress same way along with php-fpm and using the Nginx container with php-fpm and faced same issue.

you find all the example files : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx