# Read-Write permissions issue for PVC in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, virtualization, azure-aks

Currently I try to setup a Nextcloud on Azure Kubernetes Service as an exercise. Basically the application seems running, but after connecting the Database, Nextcloud ending with something like...

> Please change the permissions of your storage to 0770 to prevent other people from accessing your data

I guess cause I used a `azurefile` share as persistent volume. My pvc deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nextcloud-shared-storage-claim
  labels: 
    app: nextcloud
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

I've already researched on that topic and find ways to realize the use of permissions for pods with `securityContext`. Because I've only just started with Kubernetes on Azure I struggle a bit on binding my Deployment file for nextcloud with a pod, that applies the permissions.

*To complete the post - here is the deployment file for the Nextcloud I used*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nextcloud-server
  labels:
    app: nextcloud
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod-label: nextcloud-server-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod-label: nextcloud-server-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nextcloud
        image: nextcloud:20-apache
        volumeMounts:
        - name: server-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
          subPath: server-data
      volumes:
      - name: server-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nextcloud-shared-storage-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nextcloud-server
  labels:
    app: nextcloud
spec:
  selector:
    pod-label: nextcloud-server-pod
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
```

I guess/hope that it's totally simple.

Comment: The claim name is incorrect in your deployment file, it should be `nextcloud-shared-storage-claim` and not `nextcloud-shared-storage-claim-2`.  Are you trying to change the permissions on `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake in the post - i'll correct this. In my deployment it's correct.

Comment: @NickGraham I guess... so I actually thought about changing the permission for the pvc, but if changing the permission for the path also can be a solution for the problem, I'll prefer do it like that.

Comment: To modify the permissions on a mounted volume you’ll need to execute a script after the container starts up.  Some images give you the option to copy scripts into a particular folder that are then executed at start up, check the docs to see if the image your using provides that functionality

Comment: Ok great, thank you! Can you please tell me the name of this functionallity?

Comment: According to this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/225#issuecomment-371007021) you can try specify this permissions in your storage class. Additionally [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64022263/11977760) is an example of what @NickGraham mentioned in his comment. Could you please try it and let me know if it worked?

Comment: @Jacub thanks for the information. I'll try that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer as community wiki since it might be helpful for the community. Feel free to expand.

As mentioned by @Nick Graham in the comments

> To modify the permissions on a mounted volume you’ll need to execute a script after the container starts up. Some images give you the option to copy scripts into a particular folder that are then executed at start up, check the docs to see if the image your using provides that functionality

There are few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370).

---

Additionally according to this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/225#issuecomment-371007021) you can try to specify this permissions in your storage class.