# k8s Deployment EFS VolumeMount is mounted as only root:root owner, How can I specipy specific user?

Tags: kubernetes

My Deployment VolumeMount Config.
jane-vol means EFS volume

```
 volumeMounts:
        - name: jane-vol
          mountPath: /mnt/utils
          subPath: utils
```

In my pod, I can see the volume mounted as a root

```
$cd /mnt/
$ll
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   6144  2월  4 19:42 utils
```

However, I want to change the root:root -> jane:jane.

How can I do this only in Deployment.

Is there a way to handle this only on Deployment?

I would appreciate if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370/kubernetes-how-to-set-volumemount-user-group-and-file-permissions

Comment: @sunlim Does the above solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you.However the solution not works for me.

Comment: @sunlim There are several solutions listed in the question above. Are all of them not suitable for you? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice, to avoid modifying the docker image just for this use case, would be to add an `initContainer` that modifies the volume mount user permissions:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/

Comment: Is there any way to do it through fsgroup?