# CrashLoopBackOff on my pods when trying to write in my volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm running minikube on my old macbook and i'm trying to get a irc server up.

I have mounted a folder from my host into my node:

```
minikube start --mount --mount-string="/Users/admin/Documents/ircd/conf:/ircd/conf"
```

So, my local folder /Users/admin/Documents/ircd/conf is mounted in my /ircd/conf node folder.

Then, i mounted my  /ircd/conf (from node) into my pod. This is my deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment metadata:   name: ircd-deployment labels:
    app: servidor spec:   replicas: 2   selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: ircd-pod
      app: servidor         template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: ircd-pod
        app: servidor
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: inspircd
        image: inspircd/inspircd-docker
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6667
          name: clientes
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: servicios
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /inspircd/conf
          name: conf
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        hostPath:
          path: /ircd/conf
          type: Directory
```

My pod gets a CrashLoopBackOff error and when I run the kubectl logs [pod] i get:

```
        ##################################
        ###                            ###
        ###   Can't write to volume!   ###
        ###    Please change owner     ###
        ###        to uid 10000        ###
        ###                            ###
        ##################################

Cannot open /inspircd/conf/key.pem for writing
Cannot open /inspircd/conf/cert.pem for writing
Cannot open /inspircd/conf/dhparams.pem for writing
```

Inside my host i've both chown 10000 and chmod 777 that folder, but I still got the error.

What i'm I missing here?

**Note:** i know both that this kind of mount is not the best thing to do and that my chmod/chown are insecure.

thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the OS and minikube version and also if you are using Docker?

Comment: Sure! MacOS high sierra 10.13.6. minikube v1.23.2 on Darwin 10.13.6. Kubernetes v1.22.2 on Docker 20.10.8. Also I use hyperkit as vm driver

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545277/1032785

Comment: @jordanm problem solved, thank you! so, it's mandatory to use a security context?