# issue with ownership on mounted volumes in a Kubernetes Pod

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am trying to get a stateful PostgreSQL running in a tanzu k8s cluster ...

```
~> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.8", GitCommit:"5575935422cc1cf5169dfc8847cb587aa47bac5a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T13:00:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.8+vmware.1", GitCommit:"3e397df2f5dadadfa35958ec45c14b0e81abc25f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-21T16:59:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and have some trouble with it.

I use a **custom image** where postgres runs as the **postgres user** and **3 volumes** should be mounted. Now it seems k8s mounts those volumes as `root:root` and due to that the pod never spins up with this error message.

```
> kcl logs statefulset.apps/postgres-stateful
starting up postgres docker image:
postgres -D /opt/db/data/postgres/data
+ echo 'starting up postgres docker image:'
+ echo postgres -D /opt/db/data/postgres/data
+ '[' '!' -d /opt/db/data/postgres/data ']'
+ '[' '!' -O /opt/db/data/postgres/data ']'
+ mkdir -p /opt/db/data/postgres/data
+ chmod 700 /opt/db/data/postgres/data
chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/db/data/postgres/data': Operation not permitted
```

This relates to the `docker-entrypoint.sh` running inside the container upon creation. Now I have come to the point where it looks like I have to make sure the container is being run by the `postgres` user (which is defined in the `USER` directive of the [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/Trd90zu0) my custom image is based upon). When I run the image directly (either `podman run ...` or `kubectl run ...`) everything works.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370/kubernetes-how-to-set-volumemount-user-group-and-file-permissions) on the issue which implies this being a solution

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  # specification of the pod's containers
  # ...
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1234
```

I have adopted this pattern to the statefulSet I am using, but seem not to be able to make it work.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres-stateful
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: docker-dev-local.intern.net/ina/postgresql:14.1-scm-debian-bullseye-build-74-4
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: postgres-configuration
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgresdb
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-data
          mountPath: /opt/db/data/postgres/data
        - name: pv-backup
          mountPath: /opt/db/backup/postgres
        - name: pv-arch
          mountPath: /opt/db/backup/postgres/arch
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000   # postgres UID
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
      - name: pv-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pgdata33-pvc
      - name: pv-backup
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pgbackup33-pvc
      - name: pv-arch
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pgarch33-pvc
```

Now I am wondering whether the location of the `securityContext` (same level as `containers` & `volumes`) may be wrong. Can anybody kindly advise on this matter?

Comment: What type of PVs are you using?

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/1zLTxYFr) is the `storage.yml` which this topic here was based upon. I have changed my strategy since yesterday though, so I am not 100% sure whether this Topic ist still valid. Based on the advise from a colleague I am trying to use a `initContainer` to set the access rights. before starting the acutal postegres container. Still can not get that running neither really. I guess I leave this topic alive still and will post my solution once found.

Answer (score 0):

`fsGroup` requires support from the storage.

As you've confirmed, you are using `hostPath` volumes.
In this case `fsGroup` is not supposed to work.
It's disabled for `hostPath` for security reasons.

So yes, generally init container (run under root user) is the only viable option for `hostPath`.