# Apache2 creating /var/lock/apache2.XXXXXXXXXX

Tags: kubernetes, apache2

I am deploying my application in a kubernetes pod which is read-only in the cluster.
Also, in entrypoint.sh I am starting apache2 server using

```
apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

This is trying to create some folder in the read only pod resulting in this error:

```
mktemp: failed to create directory via template '/var/lock/apache2.XXXXXXXXXX': Read-only file system
chmod: missing operand after '755'
```

How can I avoid this. Please note that I have tried to create this tmp file at the docker image creation time and applied that image and it is still giving same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can prevent Apache from creating this file.  The [DefaultRuntimeDir directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaultruntimedir) changes its location, but you can't prevent it from creating its lock file.

What you can do, though, is mount an [`emptyDir` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) in your pod.  This is temporary writable pod-local storage.  That will let you create read-write "islands" within an otherwise read-only container filesystem.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: apache-var-lock
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - image: httpd
          volumeMounts:
            - name: apache-var-lock
              mountPath: /var/lock
```

Comment: Thanks @David Maze, I also finally reached the same conclusion and created volume and mounted and applied the deployment. I am getting error like: "chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.jcdXCEL6Fx': Operation not permitted". Do I need to give permissions to the mounted volume or something?

Comment: If you explicitly specify the user ID in the pod spec, that will become the `emptyDir` volume's owner; see _e.g._ https://stackoverflow.com/a/64022263

Answer (score 0):

Several elements need to be synchronized for the apache application to run correctly on K8s.

1. User and Group: It is recommended to use non-root user in the Dockerfile, /etc/apache2/envvars, and in the K8s container specification.

In Dockerfile, you can create group and user

```
# Create a group and user
RUN groupadd -g 1000 mygroup && useradd -r -u 1000 -g mygroup myuser

# Update /etc/apache2/envvars to use the new user and group
RUN sed -i 's/export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data/export APACHE_RUN_USER=myuser/g' /etc/apache2/envvars
RUN sed -i 's/export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data/export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=mygroup/g' /etc/apache2/envvars
```

In K8s pod's container spec, you can set the user and group.

```
securityContext:
  runAsGroup: 1000
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000
```

2. Volume: You need to mount the emptyDir volume to provide a writable volume for apache to access. /var/lock is required for storing lock files and /var/log is for logs

```
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: var-lock
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: var-log
      emptyDir: {}
  containers:
    - volumeMounts:
        - name: var-lock
          mountPath: /var/lock
        - name: var-log
          mountPath: /var/log
```

Also you need to set the fsGroup on K8s pod's spec, so that runAsUser can access the emptyDir volume mount.

EKS pod's spec:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
```

This should resolve ownership (chmod) & Read-Only file system error.