# Kubernetes mounted volume has root ownership

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am having a problem in my Kubernetes cluster. Currently I am running my Laravel application in kubernetes with success. Now I am trying to make the storage folder in my app a persistant volume, because it can be used to store images and stuff. My deployment looks like this now:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: laravel-api-app
  namespace: my-project
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: laravel-api-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: laravel-api-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: laravel-api-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: laravel-api-app
          image: me/laravel-api:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - name: laravel
              containerPort: 8080
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: laravel-api-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: laravel-api-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html/storage
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: laravel-api-persistant-volume-claim
```

As you can see my claim is mounted to the `/var/www/html/storage` folder. Now in my Dockerfile I set all my folders to the user `nobody` like this:

```
USER nobody
COPY --chown=nobody . /var/www/html
```

However, using this results in the following folder rights in my pod (`ls -la`):

```
drwxrwxrwx    1 www-data www-data      4096 Mar 14 18:24 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 17:43 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody          48 Mar 12 22:27 .dockerignore
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         220 Mar 12 22:27 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody         718 Mar 14 18:22 .env
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         660 Mar 14 18:22 .env.example
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         718 Mar 14 12:10 .env.pipeline
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         111 Mar 12 22:27 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         171 Mar 14 12:10 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 14 12:30 .gitlab-ci-scripts
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody        2336 Mar 14 01:13 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         174 Mar 12 22:27 .styleci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         691 Mar 14 10:02 Makefile
drwxrwxrwx    6 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 app
-rwxrwxrwx    1 nobody   nobody        1686 Mar 12 22:27 artisan
drwxrwxrwx    1 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 bootstrap
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody        1476 Mar 12 22:27 composer.json
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody      261287 Mar 12 22:27 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 14 12:10 config
drwxrwxrwx    5 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 database
drwxrwxrwx    5 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 13 09:45 docker
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         569 Mar 14 12:27 docker-compose-test.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         584 Mar 14 12:27 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody        1013 Mar 14 18:24 package.json
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody        1405 Mar 12 22:27 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx    5 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 14 18:23 public
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody        3496 Mar 12 22:27 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx    6 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 resources
drwxrwxrwx    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 routes
drwxrwxrwx    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 scripts
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         563 Mar 12 22:27 server.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar 14 18:18 storage
drwxrwxrwx    4 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 12 22:27 tests
drwxr-xr-x   38 nobody   nobody        4096 Mar 14 18:22 vendor
-rw-rw-rw-    1 nobody   nobody         538 Mar 12 22:27 webpack.mix.js
```

As you can see, my storage folder has `root/root` which I also want to be `nobody/nobody`. I thought about creating an initContainer like this:

```
initContainers:
  - name: setup-storage
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', '/path/to/setup-script.sh']
    volumeMounts:
      - name: storage
        mountPath: /path/to/storage/directory
```

With setup-script.sh containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

chown -R nobody:nobody /path/to/storage/directory
chmod -R 755 /path/to/storage/directory
```

But I have a feeling that there should be (or is) something much simpler to get the result I want.

I already tried adding securityContext with id: 65534 like so:

securityContext:
runAsUser: 65534
runAsGroup: 65534
fsGroup: 65534

But that resulted in the same `root/root` `owner/group`. The last thing I tried was creating a initContainer like this:

```
initContainers:
  - name: laravel-api-init
    image: me/laravel-api:v1.0.0
    args:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - cp -Rnp /var/www/html/storage/* /mnt
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    envFrom:
      - secretRef:
          name: laravel-api-secret
      - configMapRef:
          name: laravel-api-config
    volumeMounts:
      - name: storage
        mountPath: /mnt
```

This "should" copy all the content to `/mnt` which is the mounted location for the storage and then start the real deployment which mounts the copied data in the app. Unfortunatly this returns the error: `Init:ExitCode:127 kubernetes`, which is weird, because both of those locations do exist. One other thing with this approach that should not happen (I don't know if it will) is that once the volume contains data from a previous session (maybe after server reboot), that it doesn't tamper with the already existing data of the app.

### In short

So after this explanation and my tries, here is what I am trying to achieve. I want my Laravel application to have a Persistant Volume (the storage folder), so that I limit the developers of that Laravel app to a given storage. For instance, when I create a PV of 5GB, they cannot store more than 5GB of data for their application. This storage has to be persistant, so that after a server reboot, the storage is still there!

### Update

Here is the updated yaml with security context:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: laravel-api-app
  namespace: my-project
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: laravel-api-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: laravel-api-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: laravel-api-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: laravel-api-init
          image: docker.argoplan.nl/clients/opus-volvere/laravel-api/production:v1.0.0
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - cp -Rnp /var/www/html/storage/* /mnt
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: laravel-api-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: laravel-api-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /mnt
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 65534
            fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: laravel-api-persistant-volume-claim
```

For debugging purpose I copied my initContainer as actual container, so I can see my container logs in ArgoCD. If is is an initContainer, I can't see any logs. Using the yaml above, I see this in the logs:

```
cp: can't create directory '/mnt/app': Permission denied
cp: can't create directory '/mnt/framework': Permission denied
```

This is the live manifest, which apparantly does not contain the new security context, while I generated the app just now:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 0a4ce0e873c92442fdaf1ac8a1313966bd995ae65471b34f70b9de2634edecf9
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.10.55/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.10.55/32
  creationTimestamp: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
  generateName: laravel-api-app-74b7d9584c-
  labels:
    app: laravel-api-app
    pod-template-hash: 74b7d9584c
  name: laravel-api-app-74b7d9584c-4dc9h
  namespace: my-project
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: laravel-api-app-74b7d9584c
      uid: d2e2ab4d-0916-43fc-b294-3e5eb2778c0d
  resourceVersion: '4954636'
  uid: 12327d67-cdf9-4387-afe8-3cf536531dd2
spec:
  containers:
    - args:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - cp -Rnp /var/www/html/storage/* /mnt
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: laravel-api-secret
        - configMapRef:
            name: laravel-api-config
      image: 'me/laravel-api:v1.0.0'
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: laravel-api-init
      resources: {}
      securityContext: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt
          name: storage
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: kube-api-access-8cfg8
          readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
  nodeName: tohatsu
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
    - name: storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: laravel-api-persistant-volume-claim
    - name: kube-api-access-8cfg8
      projected:
        defaultMode: 420
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
                  path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
      message: 'containers with unready status: [laravel-api-init]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: 'False'
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
      message: 'containers with unready status: [laravel-api-init]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: 'False'
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
    - containerID: >-
        containerd://eaf8e09f0e2aceec6cb26e09406518a5d9851f94dfb8f8be3ce3e65ee47e282c
      image: 'me/laravel-api:v1.0.0'
      imageID: >-
        me/laravel-api@secret
      lastState:
        terminated:
          containerID: >-
            containerd://eaf8e09f0e2aceec6cb26e09406518a5d9851f94dfb8f8be3ce3e65ee47e282c
          exitCode: 1
          finishedAt: '2023-03-17T09:20:53Z'
          reason: Error
          startedAt: '2023-03-17T09:20:53Z'
      name: laravel-api-init
      ready: false
      restartCount: 5
      started: false
      state:
        waiting:
          message: >-
            back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=laravel-api-init
            pod=laravel-api-app-74b7d9584c-4dc9h_my-project(12327d67-cdf9-4387-afe8-3cf536531dd2)
          reason: CrashLoopBackOff
  hostIP: 192.168.1.8
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.1.10.55
  podIPs:
    - ip: 10.1.10.55
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: '2023-03-17T09:17:58Z'
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the user of this folder? It shouldn't be needed for a PersistentVolumeClaim.

Comment: I want to make sure that the Laravel project can only take up a max. amount of space on the server. I am using the application storage, so the `Storage` folder. Knowing this, I thought that when I mount the storage folder as `Persistant Volume`, I can give the volume a size of `20GB` and by doing this the Laravel application cannot store more than `20GB` of data on the host machine. Everything does work without a `Persistant Volume`, but when I mount it, it will have the `root/root` `owner/group` which resulsts in a permission denied in my Laravel app because the app runs with a non-root user

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370/kubernetes-how-to-set-volumemount-user-group-and-file-permissions

Comment: I have tried the answer that, like I mentioned in my question, but that wasn't the trick for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For dynamically provisioning of persistent volume of the required size use `storageClass` in your `laravel-api-persistant-volume-claim` definition and request storage of specific size (by using `requests` and `limits`). For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc  
  labels:
    app: jenkins-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: storage-class  
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
    limits:
      storage: 100Gi
```

You may also set `storageClassName` to `""`. In that case, default storage class in your Kubernetes cluster will be used (e.g. cloud provider's default storage class)

- Your approach for setting storage permissions on the storage folder in `initContainer` is correct. Otherwise you need to provision the storage, create data folders of the required size there and change the permissions of the folders manually before deploying the pod which contradicts the whole point of [dynamic storage provisioning on Kubernetes](https://rokpoto.com/kubernetes-storage-dynamic-provisioning/).

Note, that init container has to run as root. You can see real world example of [using init container for changing ownership and permissions of Jenkins data folder](https://rokpoto.com/backup-jenkins-file-system-snapshots/#install-jenkins-helm-chart-on-linode-kubernetes-cluster) below.

**This is an excerpt from `values.yaml` of Jenkins helm chart**, but you can take the relevant data and put to your Kubernetes manifiests.

```
  customInitContainers: 
  - name: fix-jenkins-home-permissions
    image: "alpine"
    securityContext: 
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: jenkins-home
      mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - (chmod 0775 /var/jenkins_home; chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home)
```

Disclaimer: I wrote linked articles.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! Still 2 questions. What is the difference between: `initContainers` and `customInitContainers`. Also, should I define both `requests` and `limits` for PVC's or is requests enough to limit an application to a certain storage size

Comment: Yes, i might have confused you. I've added an update to my answer. You should use `initContainers` in your Kubernetes manifests, `customInitContainers` is from `values.yaml` of jenkins helm chart. 

In order to limit you should use `limits`, in order to set a specific size you should use both.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention your k8s version. My answer might not be suitable for you, when you're using k8s below of v1.23.

Kubernetes can setup the permissions for you. Use `fsGroup` and `fsGroupChangePolicy` and k8s will take over the job for you.

```yaml
containers:
  - name: laravel-api-app
    image: me/laravel-api:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - name: laravel
        containerPort: 8080
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    envFrom:
      - secretRef:
        name: laravel-api-secret
      - configMapRef:
          name: laravel-api-config
    volumeMounts:
      - name: storage
        mountPath: /var/www/html/storage
    # this part is new
    securityContext:
      # user/group of nobody should have the highest possible id
      fsGroup: 65534
      fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
```

[Related configuration specs from k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods)

Comment: I'll try it, I am running `MicroK8s v1.25.6 revision 4565`

Comment: I tried your solution, but I am still getting an `Init:ExitCode:127`. I also tried placing that securityContext one level bove, so on the same level as `containers`, but that didn't work either? My init container is crashing, so lets focus on that first. Is my copy command correct?

Comment: You don't need the init-container anymore.

Comment: I do right? If I mount the storage pv it is empty on first run, and I need to copy the folder structure that is already in there right?

Comment: Well besided that, the mounted volume still isn't configured correctly, because I am seeing these 2 lines in the log: `cp: can't create directory '/mnt/app': Permission denied` and `cp: can't create directory '/mnt/framework': Permission denied`

Comment: `/mnt/app/` is not the path of your mount. :P

Comment: Yes it is, look at the `initContainer`. I am mounting that volume to `/mnt` and then copy everything from `/var/www/html/storage` to that `/mnt`. The folders inside `/var/www/html/storage` are: `app`, `framework` and `logs`. After the init is completed I mount that volume as `/var/www/html/storage` for the actual container. Or maybe I am seeing something wrong, could also be the case :)

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I overlooked that you had two init-containers. You need the security-group then also at your initContainer.

Comment: I already did add it to the init container :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252566/discussion-between-akop-and-a-vreeswijk).